# Copy file to randomly named directory with PowerShell

Tags: file, powershell, random, location, copy-item

```
#copies program directory

copy-item .\iphone -Recurse c:\Users\$env:username -force

#sets file I want to copy to unknown directory name as $file1

C:\Users\$env:username\iphone\.filename = $file1

#sets unknown folder location to $location1 which is a randomly named directory 
#under this subfolder in appdata\Roaming\parentfolder\23761253721536721(random //number) , 
#name is just a string of numbers

Get-ChildItem  C:\Users\$env:username\AppData\Roaming\parentfolder = $location1

//attempts to copy file to location

copy-item $file1 $location1
```

New to powershell. I'm sure I'm making this harder than it needs to be. This like my 10th script trying to do this and I feel like I'm getting further from the answer. Been on technet looking at examples and just not finding anything for setting the unknown directory path to which I'm trying to copy the file.

If with your answer you wouldn't mind explaining what the code is doing so I can learn I would appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean "randomly named"?

Comment: So when the program runs the first time it creates a folder in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\parentfolder\RandamlyNamedFolder   The folder so far has been a string of numbers. I just need to copy two files to this folder. But querying the location using get child-item is just saving the number string and when I try to copy-item it doesn't know where to copy the file b/c it just sees  copy-item file1 123131231651654

Comment: `c:\Users\$env:username` should be replaced by`$env:userprofile`. It is not guaranteed that both are the same! What if one saves his userprofile on a network drive? On `D:/`?

Comment: Oh and your code is incomplete. Please read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning a value to a variable, the variable reference needs to go on the left hand side of `=`:

```
$file1 = Get-Item C:\Users\$env:username\iphone\.filename
$location1 = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\$env:username\AppData\Roaming\parentfolder 

$file1 |Copy-Item -Destination $location1.FullName
```

Comment: If I remove "Get-Item" and just leave -$file1 = C:\Users\$env:username\iphone\.filename     this works. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have one "random folder":

```
## Translates to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming
$Parent = "$env:AppData\ParentFolder"

$Destination = Get-ChildItem -Path $Parent | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
$File = "$env:UserProfile\iphone\.filename"

Copy-Item -Path $File -Destination $Destination
```